# which ioctl command is called

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm using ioctl in my C code, which calls some ioctl command in the linux kernel Fedora 2.6.10 code, which I can easily edit and rebuild.

The ioctl command fails. How can I tell which ioctl command is called?

attached user space code. The second console_printf() is printed

```
int skfd = -1;
struct ifreq ifr;
if (( skfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 )) < 0)
{
    console_printf("ac_get_lan_link_ip_address - failed to open socket\n");
    return -1;
}
if(ioctl( skfd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr ) == -1)
{
    console_printf("ac_get_lan_link_ip_address - failed to run ioctl\n");
    ac_close(skfd);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use errno to find what exactly failed with your called of ioctl.

["Man ioctl"](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man2/ioctl.2.html)
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use `perror` to print the system error messages for such calls. They'll yield what goes wrong.